# What happens when you type !ls or !pwd or any shell command on Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, filesystems, ipython, google-colaboratory, file-structure

So while I was working on an online project on Google Colab I had to run some model which was automatically saved on Colab (wherever that was). On looking it up (using **!ls**) it was being saved in the '/content' directory which had some other files that were downloaded to Colab as a part of the project. Opening another notebook and running !ls on it showed the same but an empty '/content' directory. I noticed '/content' is also the default PWD and loading from google drive is through '/content/drive/My Drive'. **So what is '/content' and the exact file structure working behind Google Colab and how?** Can I transfer files from one notebook to another? Also any resources for more information on the same would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

/content on 2 notebooks are not the same. Because each notebook runs on a new computer in the cloud.

But if you mount drive, the directory `/content/drive/My Drive` will be the same. You can use it to transfer files between 2 notebooks.

Comment: Can you refer me to certain documentation or any other resource which might help to understand how Colab works on the whole? @korakot

Comment: There's no such detail document. You can only read from some answers here in Stack Overflow.